# Wifi Signal Strengths

Tags: router, wifi, signals

I hope that I have asked this question in the right topic.

Basically I use BT (In the U.K.) and I have problems with my router receiving a weak signal in certain rooms of the house, which, therefore makes the internet really slow in some cases it won't work at all.

I have had experience working with Virgin Media (UK) before and just changed the channel number and this worked fine, but, do not know if I would receive the same outcome on BT.

Could anyone suggest any other things that I could try alongside of the channel change in order to /hopefully/ get a stronger signal, without having to install Ethernet cable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be on SuperUser, but...

Use a program like InSSIDer to get an idea if there are any conflicting WiFi networks in your area, and set yours to a non-conflicting channel For b/g networks, the channels go from 1-11 (at least in the US), with channels 1, 6, and 11 the recommended channels to use. Also, make sure that your WiFi access point isn't next to a microwave, enclosed behind a solid metal wall, or have its Ethernet cable run along the length of a fluorescent bulb (all will cause interference and signal degradation). Placing the AP on top of a bookshelf or other high place will give it a better ability to broadcast its signal as well.